HTTP request duplication by Axios in react environment
I am making hybrid web mobile application using webview.
Sometimes http request reached nginx  and logged at access at double even same url timestamp query.
I am only generate target url with timestamp just before invoke request.
Occur this phenomenon only android webview not ios webview environment.
Has anyone experienced this phenomenon?
i didn’t intended Request duplication.
I didn't set any retry option.
Thank you.

We using multiple webviews. And same request has 0~5 minutes time intetval.

Could be Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?

I think this problem is not due to React strict mode. Problem occurred in production environment.

Essential of problem is duplication of random GUID that numbered on just before send on same device.
The problem occurs android device only.
I curious how is it possible.
